# How to make button at inline radiobutton aligned?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a CNN project for spectrogram images. The backend code is already finished, and I was told to make a GUI on HTML. I have this code for user to make a selection on epoch, learning rate, and architecture number.

```html
<style>
  label span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
</style>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form action="{{ url_for('usertest') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h5>Choose Architecture</h5>
    <hr style="width:50%;text-align:left;margin-left:0">

    <p>Please choose one of the architecture below.</p>
    <p>Note: We recommend you to choose two of our best architecture:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Architecture 1, learning rate = 0.0001, epoch = 300</li>
      <li>Architecture 4, learning rate = 0.00001, epoch = 300</li>
    </ol>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="input_arch" class="col-xl-2 col-form-label">Choose Architecture Value</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10" style="padding-top:8px;">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="radioarch" value="1"><span>1</span>
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="radioarch" value="2"><span>2</span>
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="radioarch" value="3"><span>3</span>
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="radioarch" value="4"><span>4</span>
                </label>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="input_epoch" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Choose Epoch Value</label>
      <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-top:8px;">
        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="radioepoch" value="50"><span>50</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radioepoch" value="100"><span>100</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radioepoch" value="150"><span>150</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radioepoch" value="200"><span>200</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radioepoch" value="250"><span>250</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radioepoch" value="300"><span>300</span>
                        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="input_lr" class="col-xl-2 col-form-label">Choose Learning Rate Value</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10" style="padding-top:8px;">
        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="radiolr" value="0.001"><span>0.001</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radiolr" value="0.0001"><span>0.0001</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radiolr" value="0.0002"><span>0.0002</span>
                        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="radiolr" value="0.00001"><span>0.00001</span>
                        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on my current output (image is attached below), I find that my radiobutton are not aligned neatly with each other. Is there any way to make the button looks aligned? If I have to add `<table>` tag, where should it? Or should I just omit the `<div>` tag and change it into another tag?

This is how my current output looks:
[image: sample output]

I want the output to look like this (this image is generated by Paint)
[image: sample expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a fixed width to each of them. Make sure that the width value considers the maximum text you have inside a radio option.

Alternatively you can consider flex-grid, they're a lot like tables, just that you don't need to add in very much HTML.

```css
.radio-inline {
    width: 100px;
}
```